# How to Remove a Specific Tag from an S3 file with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file stored in AWS S3 which has a tag of the 'retention' type set to '1d'.
The following example command will show this:

```
aws s3api get-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key "directory/subdirectory/My Test File.xlsx"

{
    "VersionId": "3KD8GJ4NDNVJFJ4Jjfj4j",
    "TagSet": [
        {
            "Value": "1d",
            "Key": "Retention"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to remove this tag, but *only* this tag. In the case where there is a file with two tags within the Tag Set, I don't want both to be removed -- just the Retention tag.

I've researched the [delete-object-tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object-tagging.html) documentation, which seems to indicate you can remove a *Tag Set* entirely -- but not a specific tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a function to delete a specific tag out of the box. However, I did a workaround for this some time back.

1.List the tags of the bucket via boto3 `get_bucket_tagging`

2.Delete the entire tag set of the bucket `bucket_tagging.delete`

3.Filter out the unwanted tag (Retention in your case) and reattach the rest

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have a python script which can achieve this use the boto3 library.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
s3_resource = aws_session.resource('s3')

def delete_bucket_name_tag_to_all_buckets():
    TAG_NAME = 'Retention'

    for s3_bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
        s3_bucket_name = s3_bucket.name
        print(f'Deleting tag "{TAG_NAME}" in "{s3_bucket_name}" to "{s3_bucket_name}"...')

        # catch tag error if there are no tags at all
        bucket_tagging = s3_resource.BucketTagging(s3_bucket_name)
        try:
            tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set # This throws if there are no tags
        except ClientError:
            print(f'No tag "{TAG_NAME}" in "{s3_bucket_name}", we are good...')
        saved_tags = [x for x in tags if x['Key'] != TAG_NAME]
        bucket_tagging.delete()
        bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet':saved_tags})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    delete_bucket_name_tag_to_all_buckets()
```

Hope it is helpful to you.